# Does php-fpm.conf support conditional expression?

Tags: php

I want to ahieve this function as the following code say.

```
if ( env['server_name'] == 'server1' )
       include = etc/fpm.d/server1.conf
else
       include = etc/fpm.d/other_server.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the latest version of PHP this is not currently supported.

You are already connecting to an FPM Server so there would never be a valid use case for this example.